# How to match a Scala Object type, like None or Nil, in a Shapeless Poly?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Say you have this HList

```
val l = Some(1) :: Nil :: HNil
```

and you want to create a shapeless Poly function that will match with one implicit on the `Nil`, but with a different implicit on the `Some`. Naively, we might think this would work:

```
object matcher extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseNil = at[Nil.type](x => 0)
  implicit def caseSome[T] = at[Some[T]](x => 1)
}
```

However this fails spectacularly and try as I might I can't seem to create a shapeless `Poly` that will match a Scala Object type, like `Nil` or `None`. It's easy enough to match a generic `List[T]` however matching `Nil` seems impossible.

Is it possible to create a shapeless `Poly` case that will match a Scala Object type? If so, how? If not, why not?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me, can you add an example how "*this fails spectacularly*" ?

Comment: Huh, well that was unexpected. Turns out I was actually trying to figure out how match inside a tuple. What I ended up needing was a type alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles just fine for me:

```
@ object matcher extends Poly1 {
    implicit def caseNil = at[Nil.type](x => 0)
    implicit def caseSome[T] = at[Some[T]](x => 1)
  }
defined object matcher

@ val l = Some(1) :: Nil :: HNil
l: Some[Int] :: Nil.type :: HNil = Some(1) :: List() :: HNil

@ l.map(matcher)
res11: Int :: Int :: HNil = 1 :: 0 :: HNil
```